# RANK PERCENTILE

Tags: powerbi

He calculado el percentil de cada valor de un conjunto de datos dentro de ese conjunto con el siguiente código DAX:

```
Occupation Percentile = 
VAR TotalSal = 
    [Salary Total]
RETURN
    IF(
        HASONEVALUE(Data[Id No]),
        COALESCE(
            DIVIDE(
                --Numerator (below) counts values that are < the EMP's salary in the Occupation Group
                CALCULATE(
                    COUNTROWS(Data),
                    FILTER(
                        ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[Occupation]),
                        Data[Salary] < TotalSal
                    )
                ),
                --Denominator (below) counts the total employees in the Occupation segment 
                CALCULATE(
                    COUNTROWS(Data),
                    ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[Occupation])
                )
            ),
            0
        )
    )
```

Quiero que ese cálculo me de un rango de percentiles que empiece en `0` y acabe en `100%` ya que para un conjunto de datos el primer valor es `4%` , para otro conjunto de datos el percentil empieza en `1%` y rara vez el valor más grande del cálculo acaba en `100`...
Habría alguna manera de añadir a mi código algún statement que que consiga realizar esto?

Gracias